# react-admin without Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

how can i use **react-admin** without **material UI**?
I want to use react-admin without material
example: replace it with a boostrap or another design library

Answer (score 3):

[create your own component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component)

in this link you will see how you can create your own input without using material ui
for example:

```
const MyInput = ({ source, record }) => {
  return (
    <Labeled source={source} label="test">
      <Field name={source} component="input" placeholder="latitude" />
    </Labeled>
  );
};
```